# threading this method produces a segfault, why?

Tags: c++, multithreading, glfw

So im using GLFW and the following method works when called in my main method

```
void Display::run() {
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */



        /* Swap Buffers And Poll */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}
```

but when i try to run it on a separate thread i get a segfault

```
std::thread t1(&Display::run, this);
```

any ideas? ask if you want any more of the code

Edit:
main.cpp

```
#include "src/support/Display.h"

int main() {
    Display* d;
    d->start();
    return 0;
}
```

Display.h

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <exception>
#include <thread>


class Display {

private:
    GLFWwindow* window;
    std::thread* displayThread;

    void run();

public:
    Display();
    void start();
    void close();
};

/* Exceptions */
struct GLFWNotInitilizedException : public std::exception
{
    const char * what () const throw ()
    {
        return "ERR: Could Not Initialize GLFW";
    }
};

struct WindowNotCreatedException : public std::exception
{
    const char * what () const throw ()
    {
        return "ERR: Could Not Create Window";
    }
};
```

Display.cpp

```
#include "Display.h"

Display::Display() {
    //init glfw
    if (!glfwInit())
        throw GLFWNotInitilizedException();

    //create window and its context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        throw WindowNotCreatedException();
    }

    //make windows context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    //run(); //this works instead of calling start() which puts run() into a thread

}

/* begins the rendering of the display window contents in seperate thread */
void Display::start() {
    std::thread t1(&Display::run, this);
    displayThread = &t1;
}

/* renders contents of display window */
void Display::run() {
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) //seg fault is output here
    {
        /* Render here */



        /* Swap Buffers And Poll */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}


/* to be used when closing display window */
void Display::close() {
    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
    displayThread->join();
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
}
```

Comment: We should not have to ask to see more of the code, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/ and http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html

Comment: @JonathanWakely hopefully this will make it clearer, sorry if im not asking in the correct manner as i have never had to resort to asking on this site

Comment: d->start(); uses a garbage pointer, you didn't make d point to anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Display* d;
```

You haven't created an object here, just an  uninitialised pointer.

```
d->start();
```

This calls a member on a nonexistent object. When it tries to access any members in the `run()` function it just accesses garbage because there is no object.

You probably want to create an object like this:

```
Display d;
d.start();
```

Also your start function will terminate the program because you don't join the thread before it is destroyed. You should learn the basics of C++ object lifetime before trying to use threads and pointers like this.

Stop using pointers until you understand the basics. `displayThread` should be an actual `std::thread` not just a pointer to some `std::thread` that goes out of scope.

Then you can just do:

```
void Display::start() {
    displayThread = std::thread(&Display::run, this);
}
```

Make sure you call `displayThread.join()` before it is destroyed, e.g in the `Display` destructor.

Answer (score 2):

```
//make windows context current
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
```

This makes it active on the **CURRENT** thread. Run this on the thread where you want to render and it should work. Currently it's in the constructor.

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thanks!